# Injecting a DLL without a need to install Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, dll

I create a C# application with an injector in it. I'm using CreateRemoteThread & LoadLibrary technique to inject a C++ DLL into another process.

It works fine on my desktop which has VS 2008 installed but It doesn't work with my laptop which does not have VS 2008 installed.

I installed VS 2008 to my laptop and it's been working fine since then.

My question is Do I need to install the entire VS 2008 product (about 4GB) in order to have my program work properly or Do I just need to install or update certain components for it to work?

Even though my laptop is working fine right now but I don't want to waste a good chunk of hard drive for something that I don't really need. And It's always good to learn.

Thanks in advance

Andrew

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing the C++ runtime on the target machine. You can either:

1. Install the redistributable package for the runtime on the target machine.
2. Link to the runtime statically using the /MT switch.

Comment: hmmm..I'm sure my laptop had MS Visual C++ Redistributable 2008 installed but it didn't work. I had to install a whole VS 2008 to make it worked; it's kind of odd to me.